# TypeScript React Native property 'target' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: typescript, react-native, compiler-errors

I'm making input component in typescript for my mobile app. I'm trying to handle change of the text in text input with useState hook, so I created this:
`const [password, setPassword] = useState('');`
now I have a input component:
`<TextInput value={password} onChangeText={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />`, and I get an error which says: "property 'target' does not exist on type 'string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onChangeText` prop takes as a parameter the input text value, so you don't need to access `e.target.value`. Just use it like this:

```
<TextInput value={password} onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)} />
```